# Sublime Emmet doesn't expand conflict

Tags: macos, sublimetext, sublimetext3, emmet

(this is on a OSX latest 10.9.x)
Some of the shortcuts work with the tab, others not..
for example:

```
.class>ul>li*5>a
```

when tabbing gives

```
.class>ul>li*5><a href=""></a>
```

while

```
div.class
```

gives correctly

```
<div class="class"></div>
```

Also html:5, input:radio expansion doesn't work (only on CTRL+E).

Should I look my key mappings? Could something from OSX be interfering? (I use OPTION+TAB to switch windows with the help of Karabiner...

Comment: it worked okay for me, osx 10.9 and sublimetext3 maybe it really is something on your configs, maybe you shold list the other plugins you have installed?

Comment: Rather than looking at all plugins installed, you may want to first try entering `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the ST console. Then try inserting as normal. If it's another ST plugin performing an action, the command name will be listed. If you don't recognize the name of the command, you can use something like [FindKeyConflicts](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/FindKeyConflicts) to see what package it's associated with. The above is a plugin I wrote, but I'm sure there are other plugins that do the same thing. In most cases, the name of the command is enough to find the offending plugin.

Comment: I tabbed on html:5 and this was logged: command: insert_best_completion {"default": " ", "exact": false}

Comment: Thanks @skuroda, I found my answer there: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/363 . Conflict with ST's autocomplete. Commented it out, and we're good. I guess now I'm missing some out of the box snippets but well.

Comment: You can also add your answer so I can accept it, this might help someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glad that helped.

Rather than looking at all plugins installed, you may want to first try entering sublime.log_commands(True) in the ST console. Then try inserting as normal. If it's another ST plugin performing an action, the command name will be listed. If you don't recognize the name of the command, you can use something like FindKeyConflicts to see what package it's associated with. The above is a plugin I wrote, but I'm sure there are other plugins that do the same thing. In most cases, the name of the command is enough to find the offending plugin.

---

Also adding your solution here to make it a bit more clear.

I found my answer there: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/363. Conflict with ST's autocomplete. Commented it out, and we're good. I guess now I'm missing some out of the box snippets but well.

---

If you would like to see the default snippets, without having to search/extract them manually, you can try using https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer. Another plugin I wrote to help with viewing those packaged files/plugins.

Comment: Just to note that I didn't use your FindKeyConflicts plugin (although I will for other things for sure as I have many conflicts) but I just googled "insert_best_completion".

Comment: No problem, I didn't really expect you to.  Every so often,  there's something obscure where it helps.  Though google is a great alternative :)